# How can i fail jmeter test if there is at least one false condision in FOR loop in beanshell script?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have test with small beanshell-script when i get from csv-file some names (like cars,telephones,blabla) and i have to check this names in html from previous test-step. Result of every check i have to write in other file. My issue here is mark this step to red color if at least one name wasn't find in html. Code here:

```
String Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
try {   
            File file = new File(vars.get("pathtocsv"));
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = reader.readLine();

            if (line != null) {
                 String[] parts = line.split(",");

                    try{
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(vars.get("pathtoresults"), true);
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                        PrintWriter pw = new  PrintWriter(bw);
                        for(String i : parts) {
                            String utf8String= new String(i.getBytes("windows-1251"), "UTF-8");
                            if(Response.contains(utf8String)){
                                pw.println("Response contain element: " + i);
                            }
                            else{
                                pw.println("!!! Response doesn't contain element: " + i);
                                Failure=true;
                                FailureMessage = "!!! Response doesn't contain element: " + i;
                                log.warn( "!!! Response doesn't contain element " + utf8String); 
                                prev.setResponseCode("400");
                        }


                        }
                        pw.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prev` is a shorthand to [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance so you can conditionally mark sampler as failed from the PostProcessor using [prev.setSuccessful(false)](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSuccessful-boolean-) method.

---

Be aware that Beanshell is [not the recommended scripting option](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), starting from JMeter version 3.1 users are strongly encouraged to switch to [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as Groovy is more Java compliant, has [a lot of JDK enhancements](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) and performs much better. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can fail parent sampler by marking success as false:

```
  prev.setSuccessful(false);
```